# 8085 SBC EPROM Operation

Tags: complexity-theory

in a single board computer built around a 8085 processor, like in the old arcade/pinball games - what is the “role” of the EPROMs - am i correct, that they contain the code that the microprocessor runs..? i am most wondering if they are only active at turn-on, sending an instruction set to the microprocessor just once...? -or- are they like the RAM constantly active and always working with the processor..?? - in the 1984 pinball i am looking at, the 8085 is tied to (3) 8155 RAM ICs that are setup for both inputs and outputs - during operation they control the game and receive feedback from the game’s features/controls - I/O stuff - i am wondering if the (2) EPROMs are only active at turn-on setting up the processor -or- do they play an on-going role as the player plays the pinball - etc…..?? - Thank you`

Comment: Seems more appropriate for [retrocomputing.se].

Comment: Did you just use a random tag? This question has nothing to do with complexity theory